# Get Values from Multiple select Box In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, select

I  have a multiple select box:

```
<select name="tar[]" multiple="multiple" style="height:100px;" id="select1">
            <?php foreach($lists as $list){ ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $list['des_id']; ?>"><?php echo $list['designation']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>

            </select>
```

At controller i am trying to get the values of selected fields,but failed to get that and i am getting values like 2 or 3.

```
$target = $this->input->post('tar');
                  print_r($target);die;
```

Am i doing right??please guide me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay i got the answer...

here is i am wrong,just i have to define the array in controller:

```
$target['tar'] = $this->input->post('tar');
print_r($target);die;
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure but try this to get all tars

```
foreach($this->input->post("tar") as $tar){
    echo $tar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Core PHP style,because Core PHP is the top of all framework:

```
if(isset($_POST['tar'])){
foreach ($_POST['tar'] as $tar_value){
        print "You are selected $tar_value<br/>";
        }
}
```